# How to bring all conda environments into one folder

Tags: python, environment-variables, anaconda, conda

I am on WIN10 with conda version 4.3.23 and anaconda-script.py Command line client (version 1.6.0).

I would like to activate environment `new36`, but before activating an environment `conda info --envs` gives:

```
(C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Myself>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
blender35                C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\blender35
django                   C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\django
ntl                      C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\ntl
python26                 C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\python26
python27                 C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\python27
python35                 C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\python35
python36                 C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\python36
webdev                   C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs\webdev
root                  *  C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3
```

Search path seems to be `C:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\envs` and after activating e.g. `python36` `conda info --envs` gives:

```
(python36) C:\Users\Myself>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
new36                    C:\Anaconda3\envs\dggs36
django                   C:\Anaconda3\envs\django
python26                 C:\Anaconda3\envs\python26
python27                 C:\Anaconda3\envs\python27
python35                 C:\Anaconda3\envs\python35
python36              *  C:\Anaconda3\envs\python36
webdev                   C:\Anaconda3\envs\webdev
root                     C:\Anaconda3
```

Now `blender35` and `ntl` disappeared and cannot be activated while `new36` shows up and can be activated; the search path seems to be `C:\Anaconda3\envs\`.

---

**Question:** How can I move all environments to **one** folder (and one search path)? I would like to have everything in `C:\Anaconda3\envs\`

---

My guess is that something got mixed up between conda and anaconda but I do not know which files to check to solve this problem.

Additionally, I found the `.condarc` file at `C:\Users\Myself`

```
ssl_verify: 'True'
channels:
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
  - anaconda-fusion
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
show_channel_urls: true
channel_priority: true
```

---

Edit 1: [The user guide about managing environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment) actually says

> TIP: In Windows, it is good practice to deactivate one environment before activating another.

Following this tip, I would not even be able to activate `new36`

Comment: Does this happen, perhaps, if you create a conda-environment when you are already in a conda environment? This is weird.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You mean if I created `new36` while `python36` as active? Why would `blender35` and `ntl` disappear?

Comment: You have 2 `conda` `root`s as you already discovered. However, when you call `activate`, it runs the first `activate` it finds in the `%PATH%`. After `activate` is ran, it changes the `%PATH%` which now runs the `conda info` from the second root.

Answer (score 1):

**Limitations**

You can't just move the directories from one location to another. All the scripts within an environment have references to the environment's path as listed by `conda info --envs`.

**Solution Summary**

However, you can recreate the same environment from one path to the other path. In summary you will need to gather environment information from old path, re-create environment in new path, delete the old environment, and finally delete the old root when all environments have been re-created.

**Assumptions made**

```
Old path: c:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3
New Path: C:\Anaconda3
```

**Gather environment information**

List all packages of an environment and save it to a file.

```
c:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\bin\conda list -n ntl > c:\temp\ntl.txt
c:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3\bin\conda list -n blender35 > c:\temp\blender36.txt
```

**Use the information in the file to create new environment**

*Note: The file will contain package name, version and build channel. For packages where build channel is <pip>, use pip to install.*

*Use package information from **c:\temp\ntl.txt** here*

```
C:\Anaconda3\bin\conda create -n ntl packagename==version packagename2==version ...
```

*Use package information from **c:\temp\blender35.txt** here*

```
C:\Anaconda3\bin\conda create -n blender35 packagename==version packagename2==version ...
```

**Delete old path**

We'll take the shortcut here. Drop the old path. There really is no need to drop environments individually.

```
del /S c:\Users\Myself\Anaconda3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did this mix-up happen because I may have created a new environment while having ```python36``` activated?

Comment: @Michael - No. The second installation is totally separate from the other installation. A mixup will create a second `root` environment within the active environment. You already had 2 `root` installations when you created some of those environments.